# A layout problem with Google map API

Tags: google-maps

I have a little project with Google Map API: to show a small map on page. But the Google logo and copyright word are overlap together.

**Can I move them out? And how?**

[screenshot here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/noonsleeping/4130520032/in/photostream/)

Comment: what is the target platform you are working on?

Comment: Width of the div is too small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this fairly easily with CSS, but you'd break [Google's Terms](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) (see section 7.4).

If you can't make your window bigger, you could use an alternate mapping solution, like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)

Comment: Hi, Chris, thank you very much.
I've found a map without logo in google web search, is that ONLY on GOOGLE?
via: http://www.google.com/search?q=pizza&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:zh-CN:official&hs=tUo&newwindow=1&oi=local&ct=location-input-top